# .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0 with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I've created .NET 6 project in Visual Studio 2022 but I get this error:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0. Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0

Although the `dotnet --list-sdks` outputs:

```
2.2.108 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.421 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.206 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.214 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.107 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

And `global.json`:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "6.0.302"
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like it may not be installed correctly. Try restarting VS, if that doesn't work re-install and restart your computer.

Comment: VS 2022 works just fine with .NET 6. It doesn't need a `global.json`. It's quite possible the problem is *caused* by a `global.json` targeting .NET 5 in the project or a parent folder. `global.json` settings in child folders override the settings in parent folders

Comment: @phuzi it is almost fresh VS install. I tried to restart VS and the same error appears. I will try to reinstall it.
@PanagiotisKanavos It is a new fresh console application project that I created. I added the `global.json` just because of this error.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Removing the global.json does not help anything - visual studio is straight up ignoring any method I attempt to use to use a specific SDK

Comment: I installed the specific SDK mentioned in the global.json file "6.0.301" and re-opened vs 2022 and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this late answer will help someone. I was having this same trouble with one project in Visual Studio 2022.

Running `dotnet --info` showed that I had the right .NET SDK installed but I noticed that the Runtime Environment > Base Path: was showing .NET 5.0 and while I didn't notice it I'm sure that it also indicated that a global.json file was being used.

I had created a global.json file pinning the project to .NET 5.0 the last time I worked on the project (maybe a year ago, long enough that I forgot). Deleting the now invalid global.json in the solution directory fixed my issue.

A careful consideration of what you see when running `dotnet --info` in the  folder for the project should reveal the source of this problem for Visual Studio 2022