# Visual Studio Not Using Correct .NET SDK on Visual Studio For Mac 2022

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am attempting to upgrade a project from .net 5 to .net 6

I am using Visual Studio for Mac 2022 v17.3 (I have tried Visual Studio for Mac Preview 2022 v17.4 as well but no luck there)

I have installed the .net 6 sdk onto machine. The output of `dotnet --list-sdks` is:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.419 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.422 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.400 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

The output of `dotnet --version` is:

```
dotnet --version
6.0.400
```

I have attempted both with and without a global.json. The contents of the global.json when I tried it:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.400"
  }
}
```

I also tried my other 6 sdk version,

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.300"
  }
}
```

My TargetFramework for my projects is set to net6.0

```
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

Despite all of this, here is the output when I attempt to build from Visual Studio: (building from command line works)

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/**5.0.408**/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

(bold emphasis is my own, on the sdk version)

It is only ever trying to use 5.0.408

I know there are very many questions and answers related to this issue on stack overflow, one example of which is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73064435/net-sdk-does-not-support-targeting-net-6-0-with-visual-studio-2022), the only problem is the solutions provided in the other similar questions are not resolving my issue. There seems to be some sort of caching happening and I cannot figure it out. I just want Visual Studio to use the proper SDK version.

If I run `dotnet build MySolution.sln` from the command line, it builds using the proper SDK. Visual Studio, on the other hand, does not. It only uses 5.0.408. There is not a global.json anywhere in my file structure that points to a net 5 sdk. There are no projects in my solution that Target 5, they all target 6.

Comment: There is a similar problem with targeting .NET 8.0. VS for Mac does not recognize the 8.0 SDK as installed, even though it is listed under SDK Locations in Preferences and `dotnet --version` run in a terminal window inside VS returns “8.0.100”. I think the problem may be that VS itself runs under version 7. The Details view of the About window says “Runtime: .NET 7.0.3 (64-bit)”. Build error messages refer to a file called `Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets` under a version 7.0.311 SDK directory.

Comment: In order to use the .NET 8 SDK with Visual Studio for Mac you have to enable this feature in Preferences - Other - Preview Features - Use the .NET 8 SDK if installed. Took me forever to find it out. Hopefully this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I managed to workaround it by:

- removing 5.0.408 from my machine
- removing 6.0.400 from my machine
- downloading a fresh install of 5.0.408
- downloading a fresh install of 6.0.400

If this doesnt work, I found another solution which is to uncheck "Build with MSBuild on mono" in the solution build properties. (Right click solution file, go to properties, "Build > General", uncheck)

Comment: I've tried to do like you but this didn't work.

I've removed the sdk like this:

`version="5.0.408"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/$version`

Comment: +1 for the 'Build with MSBuild on mono' trick -- that sorted it for me. Though I was using that to correct for another issue. Fun!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do like you but this doesn't work.

I've removed the SDK 5.0.408 and 6.0.401 like this:

```
version="5.0.408"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/$version

version="6.0.401"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/$version`
```

Then I've reinstalled the SDK 5.0.408 and 6.0.401.

But I always have the same error when I try to restore packages from Visual Studio.

Is there something else?

Comment: I could not figure out any other solution, I have another team member experiencing the same issue at the moment. If we determine a different solution I'll update you here

Comment: Ok we found a new solution. Right click on your solution file, go to properties, go to "Build > General", uncheck "Build with MSBuild on Mono".

Answer (score 0):

Inside of Visual Studio 2022 for Mac, I went to Tools, then SDK manager, and set this and it automatically detected the SDK after selecting this file:

[image]